# Can Blazegraph work with the Jena framework?

Tags: rdf, jena, triplestore, blazegraph

I am looking for a high availability/scale-out triple store that works with the Jena framework and came across Blazegraph. Does Blazegraph have an adaptor for the Jena framework? If not, what are high availability RDF stores that can work with the Jena framework?

Answer (score 4):

It should do if you use the standard SPARQL protocols to work with the server.  See `RDFConnection` in Jena.

Answer (score 0):

Both Stardog and Virtuoso have Jena connectors. One of them may fit your requirements.